# Why is there this extra space that is not inspect-able on chrome?

Tags: html, css

My page didn't require a horizontal scroll bar initially, but now one appears mysteriously that is beyond any of the elements that are covered on inspect on Chrome and firebug. No elements pass that blue line so I'm not sure how to fix this.

I know I can hide the scrollbar with overflow-y:hidden, but that's not the point.  It shouldn't be there at all.

**EDIT** Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S8RUp/
A bit messy, but I think it gets the point across.

[image]

Comment: only in chrome or other browsers as well? Possibly a problem with margin, padding or something similar

Comment: where is you html & css code ?

Comment: I see, html and css is way too large and complex to post. I think I could fix it if problem is identified because I've never seem this before.  It's on all browsers. It didn't happen before, just came out of nowhere.

Comment: create a Fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @diEcho Done. It's not perfect but it gets the message out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jsFiddle link has too many overflowing contents to be useful. What you can do to ease debugging is to use a bit of code like this to show you only elements that are over a threshold width:

```
// using jQuery - you can use other library or include it temporarily for debugging purposes
$('*').each(function() {
    var w = parseInt($(this).width(), 10);
    // you can put something larger than 700, depending on your situation
    if (w > 700) {
        console.log(w, this);
    }
});
```

It will have a few false positives (the `html` node for example), but you'll probably find the culprit easily enough.

Comment: That was genius advice. Spotted the problem. THANK YOU!